# apt-mirror does not mirror the i18n directory

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I need to setup a local Ubuntu mirror so the whole network doesn't need to hit remote servers in order to update and install new packages. Following a brief tutorial [found here](http://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror), I managed to get a server up and running that correctly mirrors packages from the main and restricted categories. However, when I call apt-get update on a client, I get a couple of errors such as :

```
Ign http://192.168.1.18 karmic/main Translation-fr
Ign http://192.168.1.18 karmic/restricted Translation-fr
```

Checking back on the server, I see that apt-mirror only took the `binary-amd64` directory of the mirror, and didn't take `i18n` that would provide `Translation-fr`.

The manpage for apt-mirror doesn't say anything about i18n, and Google is of no help either. How do I properly mirror i18n?

My current mirror.list file is as follows :

```
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# if you change the base path you must create the directories below with write privileges
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive karmic main restricted
deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive karmic-updates main restricted

clean http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive
```

Comment: This is a [known issue with apt-mirror](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apt-mirror/forums/forum/197335/topic/5297601). The developer is working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At our work place we sync using a plain rsync script like this one. It's nice to know what's actually happening, which files we are getting, etc.

```
#!/bin/ksh                                                                                                 

RSYNCSOURCE=rsync://se.rsync.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
BASEDIR=/export/install/mirror/ubuntu

rsync --recursive --times --links --hard-links \
      --exclude "Packages*" --exclude "Sources*" \
      --exclude "Release*" --no-motd \
      ${RSYNCSOURCE} ${BASEDIR}

rsync --recursive --times --links --hard-links \
      --delete --delete-after --no-motd \
      ${RSYNCSOURCE} ${BASEDIR}
```

It's based on these instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors/Scripts

(The important part is the sync being in two stages.)